# Why does Oracle SQL Developer have null pointer exception on startup on Mac OS

Tags: java, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

When I launch a fresh install of Oracle SQL Developer the icon bounces in the dock a bit then disappears.

When I launch it via CLI I get this error:

```
Oracle SQL Developer
 Copyright (c) 1997, 2017, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Problem creating splash screen on ETD.
    at oracle.ide.osgi.boot.SplashScreenImpl.SynchronizeWithEdt(SplashScreenImpl.java:541)
    at oracle.ide.osgi.boot.api.SplashScreen.createInstance(SplashScreen.java:66)
    at oracle.ide.osgi.boot.OracleIdeLauncher.showSplashScreen(OracleIdeLauncher.java:828)
    at oracle.ide.osgi.boot.OracleIdeLauncher.main(OracleIdeLauncher.java:109)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(EventQueue.java:1328)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(EventQueue.java:1303)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(SwingUtilities.java:1475)
    at oracle.ide.osgi.boot.SplashScreenImpl.SynchronizeWithEdt(SplashScreenImpl.java:537)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.init(Window.java:495)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:535)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:423)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:388)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:180)
    at oracle.ide.osgi.boot.OracleIdeLauncher$2.getHiddenWindow(OracleIdeLauncher.java:807)
    at oracle.ide.osgi.boot.api.SplashScreen$1.run(SplashScreen.java:61)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:303)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:764)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:717)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:711)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:89)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:734)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:199)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
A fatal error in the IDE boostraping code. Exiting ...
```

I have tried to verify the JDK version is correct, and there are no other missing dependencies. What is causing this error?

**Edit:**

Currently connected via Dell D6000 dock over minidisplay port, using DisplayLink drivers

MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2017), High Sierra v10.13.3, DisplayLinkDriver v4.0.0 (85514)

```
$ java -version
java version "9.0.4"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9.0.4+11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9.0.4+11, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

After pulling my hair out, a coworker discovered the cause: I was using multiple monitors.

It turns out the splash screen was trying to display on the main monitor but wasnt able to for some reason. Disconecting my extra displays solved the issue and allowed me to launch the application. After launching I plugged in the displays and dragged the window over to them, no issue.

**TLDR: set your main monitor to the Macbook screen or use one monitor to launch**

You can change the main monitor by using spotlight search for `displays` and then drag the white bar to your actual computers display (in my case the macbook screen).

Comment: That's not right. I develop sqldev and have at the moment 3 monitors going. This is typically a java<>video driver issue.  Can you check what version of java you are using ?

Comment: Added more details in the question, we suspect it was the DisplayLink driver that caused the issue

Comment: Sounds like. Something with java and that driver is borking. You can also try the most current Java8.

Comment: I can confirm that this is an issue. Same dock with displaylink drivers. If I startup sqldeveloper without the dock on I am fine.  I am so glad I found this, I was tearing my hair out too...

Comment: I have set an external monitor to be primary display (in order to get WebEx to work on it!). Disconnecting my external displays and starting on my MBP screen will load the application. Then plugging back in my external displays the window automatically moves to my primary display! Thanks. Shame it gives a generic error on failure though.

Comment: Can confirm its breaking with displaylink drivers as well

Comment: This bug has been tagged by OpenJDK:
https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8223158

I noticed that they have this tagged as resolved for 11.0.7 +.

Thus, one way around this bug on MacOS Catalina is to install the latest OpenJDK11 from here (or at least newer than the one tagged 11.0.7):
https://adoptopenjdk.net/nightly.html?variant=openjdk11&jvmVariant=hotspot

This is working on Catalina for me WITHOUT needing to open the clamshell to launch the application, which is much preferable to the workaround for me.

Comment: In can see this fixes my issue :-)

Comment: Run into the same problem, in my case I was keeping the lid closed and having the external monitor as the main monitor. Solution that worked for me: open the lid, launch SQLDeveloper, close the lid :).

Answer (score 0):

Exactly that exception appeared for me with macOS 12.6.1 and single monitor. Update of SQL Developer 22.2.0.173.2018 to 22.2.1.234.1810 helped.